# symfony2: service access in controller throws exception - "Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object"

Tags: php, symfony, service, dependency-injection

I made a service in `src\trollmaster\TrollBundle\Services\DefaultService.php`

```
namespace trollmaster\TrollBundle\DefaultService;

class DefaultService
{
    protected $example;

    protected function exampleFunction()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My Resources\config\services.yml:

```
services:
    trollmaster.default_service:
        class: trollmaster\TrollBundle\DefaultService
```

and command  `php app/console container:debug` returned name of my service correctly, but when I want to call this service in Controller's Construct:

`$this->DefaultService = $this->get("trollmaster.default_service");`

I see this error:

`Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object`

What am I doing wrong?

---

edit:

When I want to define controller as service

```
/**
 * @Route(service="DefaultController")
 */
class DefaultController
```

I got error:

```
ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "DefaultController" from namespace "trollmaster\TrollBundle
```

Comment: Does your Controller extend the Controller class? It is that class that has the `get` method

Comment: What are you trying to achive?

Comment: Just access to my service in Controller: $this->DefaultService.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the container is injected into controllers that implement`ContainerAwareInterface`

... (i.e. by extending `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`) ...

... via **setter-injection**.

---

*TLDR:* setter-injection is performed **after** the object has been constructed.

As a result you aren't able to do ...

```
$service = $this->get('service');
// ... or ...
$service = $this->container->('service');
```

... inside the `__construct()` method because the `setContainer()` method wasn't called and `$this->container` is not set yet.

You can read more about the different types of injection in the **[documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html)**.

---

Have a look at the following code parts:

- `Controller` extends `ContainerAware` **[here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L35)**
- `ContainerAware` provides the `setContainer()` method **[here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerAware.php#L37)**

Comment: So I can simply call `$this->DefaultService = $this->get("trollmaster.default_service");` for example in indexAction() method :)

Comment: yes, or even better: don't extend `Controller` but configure your controller class as a service explicitly - then inject the `trollmaster.default_service` among all the other service dependencies directly into the constructor. (as Markus suggested)

Comment: so, how should looks exampleController with exampleAction and exampleService with exampleMethod? I have got little problems to make it correctly :(

Answer (score 1):

This is because the constructor isn't aware of the container (like nifr explained.). But you can [define your controller itself as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html). This would be best practice i guess, although I don't know what you are trying to achive.